# jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property

Tags: jquery

```
var arr = [{
    value: 'a'
}];
var getTest = function() {
    jQuery.each(arr, function(i, val) {

        if (val.value == "a") {
            return val;
        }
    });
}

alert(getTest().value);
```

> jquery-3.1.0.js:3793 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var arr = [{
    value: 'a'
}];
var getTest = function() {
    var toRet;
    jQuery.each(arr, function(i, val) {
        if (val.value == "a") {
            toRet = val;
        }
    });
    return toRet;
}

alert(getTest().value);
```

`jQuery.each` is actually a function and you are returning value there and not to your function `getTest()`. This is working solution.